# Passthrough _ sender UIViewController action method

Tags: swift, xcode

How can I pass  through the sender of an action outlet like this:

```
@IBAction func doPlay(_ sender: Any) {
    someMethod(???)
}
```

What means the underscore?

Answer (score 0):

just write

```
someMethod(sender)
```

The underscore just means that the argument "sender" doesn't need a label.